# React-Router-Dom: The content of a page is not displayed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm learning how to use ReactJS, I have installed `react-router-dom`.

So in my App.js:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <Container>
            <NavBar />
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/">
                        <Home />
                    </Route>
                    <Route path="/team">
                        <Team />
                    </Route>
                </Switch>
        </Container>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

I have create a NavBar in which I have some link like this:

```
return(
        <>
        <Container fluid="md">
            <Navbar bg="dark" variant="dark" >        
            <Nav className="mr-auto">
                <Link to="/" className="Text">Home</Link> 
                <Link to="/team" className="Text">Team</Link>         
            </Nav>
            </Navbar>
        </Container>
        </>
    )
```

Now my problem is App.js shows only the Home content, and if I click in the NavBar on Team text, the url changes (to localhost:3000/team) but the page content remains always the Home.js one.

How can I do to show the Team content when I click on Team text in the NavBar?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo need to specify which component is rendering with each path, like this:

```
<Route path="/team" component={Team}>
```

Comment: I forget also to add exact to the home component. Thank you